# How to insert text into text field using buttons without resetting it

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

*I have commented the solution (using magnus's suggestion) below*

I currently have a button+span setup for typing numbers into a calculator application. I would like the user to have the ability to both click the buttons AND type using a keyboard. Ideally, the user could type 2 letters and then use buttons for 2 letters without any problems.

Or maybe this is the wrong way to go about it? Instead I should offer the choice of one or the other to the user.

I am not sure. Any guidance you could give would truly be appreciated. Thank you for taking the time to read this.

(Not sure what code to really include, so I opted to link to the pen instead)

Here is the pen: https://codepen.io/yinuo/pen/dRYJEj

```
    function update(){
    totalString = inputs.join("");
    $("#steps").html(totalString);
  }

  function getTotal(){
        totalString = inputs.join("");
    $("#steps").html(eval(totalString));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just listen for the `keyup`-event:

```
document.addEventListener('keyup', function(evt) {
  var key = evt.key.toLowerCase();
  // Add more keys to list to listen for other buttons
  if (key in ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']) {
    // May need to map keys to specific ids
    document.getElementById(key).click()
  }
})
```

Comment: You also need to update the value so get the current value entered from keyboard or your panel and add the new key at the end. You should do that with both the keyboard input and the panel button click.

`// get current value
var currentValue = $("#steps").text();
// add key value to current value
var newValue = currentValue+key;
// update current value
$("#steps").text(newValue);`

Comment: First time I've come across this function. Every answer really is just one unknown function away haha.

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Is there anyway to insert w/e the user puts in? For example, even if they type a symbol it would still insert.

Answer (score 1):

After the great reply from Magnus, and some experimenting I settled on a code that allows the user to type w/e they want into the field.

```
 document.addEventListener('keyup', function(evt) {
  var key = evt.key.toLowerCase();
    if (key in ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']) 
    getValue(key);

  else
    document.getElementById(key).click()
})



function getValue(input){   
  inputs.push(input);
   update();
       console.log(inputs);
}
```